# Copy Range from particular Sheet in Excel OpenXML Doc to specific location in second OpenXML Excel Sheet (INCLUDING DRAWING contained within Range)

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-office, openxml-sdk

I have been looking for this snippet for quite a while and either:

1. I am asking Google the wrong question,
2. I am using the wrong approach or
3. no one has done this yet (unlikely, I know).

I have a Template OpenXML Spreadsheet document with Drawings and Data/Computations on 10-15 Sheets with 10-15 per sheet. I wish to copy everything from a particular range on a particular sheet from the template file ie.['SheetZ1'!$X1$#:$Y1$#] of file1.xlsx to a particular position in a particular sheet in the output OpenXML spreadsheet file ie.['SheetZ2'!$X2$#:$Y2$#] in file2.xlsx. If it helps, each of the ranges are in a "Named Range" and I would perfer to address them by Range Name.

So my business problem is: given a template spreadsheet full of Named Ranges containing Data, Calulations and Drawings, go to sheet Z and copy that range to my output OpenXML Spreadsheet into its correct location.

If anyone has a snippet, knows of a snippet, or knows someone with a snippet, I would really appreciate it. I would like the snippet in VB.Net however I could convert C# as well.

I do not wish to come off as a jerk or ungrateful, however I rarely find much value in comments like "well I have never done it, however you should be able to ... and then I think you can move that to .... and then maybe do this... or something like that..." I really just need a working snippet and I will fill in the rest.